# Is there python interpreter command for error-checking only but does not run the program

Tags: python, command-line, runtime-error

I only want to check my python file for errors, but I don't want to execute it. Is there any some sort of command argument for that?

If there are errors, then the interpreter will off course not run the program. But if there is no error, then the program will be executed, what I want is the interpreter to not do anything and quit the interpretation.

Comment: Visual Studio Code has supporting this features

Comment: I don't know a command line tool but the built-in function "[compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile)" can help to easily create such tool.

Comment: use python linting tool to check for your errors its command line based obviously and make your custom script that runs linter if no errors run the code else not